# How to automatically send text messages to specific users, using python?

Tags: python, dictionary, automation

I want to be able to send a text message to specific users of a service. My current code I have to go into it and specify which customer is being referenced, `id`. I would like to be able to use a dictionary (or csv file) to house the customer information and send texts to each customer with their specific information.

I have the script below for sending the messages:

```
import smtplib
import pandas as pd
from providers import PROVIDERS

def send_sms_via_email(
        number: str,
        message: str,
        provider: str,
        # sender_cred: tuple,
        sender_email: str = 'sample@email.com',
        subject: str = "Test Python Text",
        smtp_server: str = "sampleserver.com",
        smtp_port: int = 25):
        # sender_email, email_password = sender_cred
        receiver_email = f"{number}@{PROVIDERS.get(provider).get('sms')}"
        
        email_message = f"Subject:{subject}\nTo:{receiver_email}\n{message}"
        
        smtp = smtplib.SMTP()
        smtp.connect('sampleserver.com', 25)
        login = pd.read_csv('logindetails.csv')
        smtp.login(login.Username[0], login.Password[0])
        smtp.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, email_message)

from customers import CUSTOMERS
id= '6101024714'
body = f"Hello,\n The customer {CUSTOMERS.get(id).get('loc_Name')} is "\
    f"experiencing delays on order {CUSTOMERS.get(id).get('Delivery')}."
    

send_sms_via_email('5555555555', body, 'T-Mobile')
```

This works, but it requires I manually change the id, phone number, and carrier. In this example CUSTOMERS is a dictionary with customer order information, including POC information and PROVIDERS is a dictionary with phone carrier information.

Comment: This doesn't sound too complicated with the simple csv reader and readlines method, but what have you tried already?

Comment: @JustLudo I've been manually changing the id, phone number and cell phone carrier. I'm trying to figure out how to automate this process

Comment: Take a look at the CSV reader documentation. Just create a CSV and read it using your script, put your code inside the for loop over readlines. (https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

Comment: Can you provide an example? i'm still having trouble

Comment: Maybe you can adjust your original question and add your new code and error description. Usually someone can help you with that. Also: https://realpython.com/python-csv/ (first result on google ....)